# What is the structure of a GAM fit with `mgcv::bam()` with the `rho` parameter set?

Tags: autoregressive, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

If I fit the model `mgcv::bam(y~s(x), rho=0.8)`, where y and x are ordered by time, my understanding is that the model can be described in math notation as:

$
y_t = \beta0+f(x_t)+\epsilon_t\\
\epsilon_t = rho * \epsilon_{t-1} + w_t\\
w_t \sim normal(0, \sigma)
$

Is this correct?
Also is the maximum likelihood estimate of the model equivalent to minimizing the square of $w$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to think of the model `mgcv::bam(y ~ s(x), rho = 0.8)` as being equivalent to

$$
y_t = \beta_0 + f(x_t) + \varepsilon_t
$$

where $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \hat{\sigma}^2\boldsymbol{\Lambda})$ and $\boldsymbol{\Lambda})$ is the first order correlation matrix

$$
\boldsymbol{\Lambda} = \begin{pmatrix}
1          & \rho       & \rho^2     & \cdots & \rho^{n-1} \\
\rho       & 1          & \rho       & \cdots & \rho^{n-2} \\
\rho^2     & \rho       & 1          & \cdots & \rho^{n-3} \\
\vdots     & \vdots     & \vdots     & \ddots & \vdots     \\
\rho^{n-1} & \rho^{n-2} & \rho^{n-3} & \cdots & 1          \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with $\rho = 0.8$.

But this arises from the assumed first order AR process

$$\varepsilon_t = \rho \varepsilon_{t-1} + \eta_t$$

with $\eta_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \hat{\sigma}^2)$. (Which is what you wrote but with the notation from my own lecture notes/slides so as to not confuse myself.)

This is essentially a generalised least squares problem, which I understand will seek to minimise [the squared Mahalanobis length of the residual vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) $\eta_t$ (your $w_t$).

Comment: Thank you. I had read your notation, N(0,σ^2Λ), before without really understanding it. The explicit example for the AR(1) model here really helped.

Comment: Gavin Simpson and David Lawrence Miller shared a lot of valuable insights regarding this question on twitter (https://twitter.com/JohsEnevoldsen/status/1481922275632898056)